# Select Folder and Filename to Save a new file for 32-bit and 64-bit MS-Access-2016

Tags: ms-access, filedialog

I am trying to get a full path and filename using the file dialog from MS Access VBA.
In my MS-Access project I want to be able to save data into a user selectable folder and filename.
To select the folder and filename MS-Access provides the FileDialog() function.

[--> FileDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/access.application.filedialog?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm12592);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

But the latest versions of MS-Access (especially the 64-bit version) the FileDialog function does not support the msoFileDialogSaveAs option any more.

Is there any way to get a folder and filename from the user using an API function like the FileDialog Object for the latest version of MS-Access?

Answer (score 0):

There is support, but you need a reference to *Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library*:

[image]

Enums:

[image]

Example:

```vb
Public Function FileSaveDialog( _
    ByVal Filter As String, _
    ByVal Extension As String) _
    As String

    Dim FilterIndex As Long
    Dim FileName    As String
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)  ' 2
        For FilterIndex = 1 To .Filters.Count
            If (InStr(LCase(.Filters(FilterIndex).Description), LCase(Filter)) > 0) And _
                (LCase(.Filters(FilterIndex).Extensions) = LCase(Extension)) Then
                .FilterIndex = FilterIndex
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If .Show Then
            FileName = .SelectedItems(.SelectedItems.Count)
        End If
    End With
    
    FileSaveDialog = FileName

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, many thanks for your response. 
Can you please alos let me know, how Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library solved this problem. Which function does solve this problem and how do I use it. Do you perhaps have any example code?

Comment: This library holds the enums/constants (i.e. `msoFileDialogSaveAs`) - see picture, please.

Comment: When I execute the FileDialog with option  msoFileDialogSaveAs  then I get the following message:
Microsoft Access: FileDialog: Object does not support this property or method

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.